# NPM download count by package version?

Tags: npm

I know there's a [public API](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/download-counts.md) for getting NPM download counts, as well as tools built on top of it like [npm-stat](https://npm-stat.com/) and [npmtrends](http://www.npmtrends.com/). However, I'd like to get more granular and see downloads for a particular package by version. I don't see this documented in the API docs anywhere. Is it possible?

Comment: Looks like you can't specify version (

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Per version download counts](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/download-counts.md#per-version-download-counts) are now available from the npm registry.

> Download count for specific versions of a package are only available for the previous 7 days. They have a unique API end point
>
> `GET https://api.npmjs.org/versions/{package}/last-week`
>
> Note: for scoped packages, the `/` needs to be percent encoded. (`@slack/client` -> `@slack%2Fclient`).

They're also displayed in the `Versions` tab of the package's home page.